# Multiple APIs with different application name

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm pretty new in Android development

I have 2 different APIs that each has their own `<application android:name>`

I already successfully implemented 1 API, so I have this in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:name="com.soomla.SoomlaApp">
```

And now I'm about to start to implement another one that has this

```
<application android:name="com.xxx.AnAwesomeApp">
```

From what I know, we can only have 1 `<application>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` of the app.
How can I implement both of these API at the same time?

Thank you...

Comment: APIS you are using are library projects or jar

Comment: What does "API" mean?

Comment: @  phuc_tran "API" means third party library

Comment: Oh than it is not possible. If you have open source code than it is possible by multilevel inheritance

Comment: I mean at least one should be in editable mode

Comment: well, if multiple inheritance is possible I can create a new application that inherits from both of the APIs, but I don't think that's possible in Java